# How to prevent "0" as the first character and limit number of characters allowed in UITextField using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I want to achieve following:

1. Have a decimal keypad. Which means user will be able to enter Double
   values. (Needless to say "." will be limited one)
2. Prevent "0" characters as the first characters. (i.e.: There should
   not be values like "003" "01" "000012" etc.)
3. Limit the character count to 10.
4. Only allow numbers. No Copy-Paste text values.

I am using decimal keypad. Below code handles first and third item above:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let currentString: NSString = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
    let newString = currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    return newString.count <= 10
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bellow code will check all conditions you have specified

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
    
    //Prevent "0" characters as the first characters. (i.e.: There should not be values like "003" "01" "000012" etc.)
    if textField.text?.count == 0 && string == "0" {
        
        return false
    }
    
    //Limit the character count to 10.
    if ((textField.text!) + string).count > 10 {
        
        return false
    }
    
    //Have a decimal keypad. Which means user will be able to enter Double values. (Needless to say "." will be limited one)
    if (textField.text?.contains("."))! && string == "." {
        
        return false
    }

    //Only allow numbers. No Copy-Paste text values.
    let allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "0123456789.")
    let textCharacterSet = CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: textField.text! + string)
    if !allowedCharacterSet.isSuperset(of: textCharacterSet) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: How can I input 0 to this textfield? 0 is a number.

Comment: But if we change the cursor position and try entering "0" at the start of the string, the above solution does not work. After entering some text in the string and appending zero at start by changing cursor position allows "0" too.

Comment: This is the solution for the cursor position issue.
if range.location == 0 && string == "0" {
            return false
        }

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex that define a number with <= 10 digits and not starting with 0, then use NSPredicate or NSRegularExpression to validate the entered text. Something like this:

```
func isAllowed(str: String?) -> Bool {
    let regexPattern: String = "^((?!(0))[0-9]{0,10})$"
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", regexPattern)

    return predicate.evaluate(with: str)
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return isAllowed(str: textField.text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Create this method to prevent from copy paste

```
override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if action == "paste:" {
            return false
        }        
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
```

and also you can add the following code to `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` Delegate method of textfield

```
  let searchString = (txtMobilePhone.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

        if (searchString?.length)! > 1 {

            let inverseSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: ".0123456789").inverted

            return ((string as NSString).rangeOfCharacter(from: inverseSet).location == NSNotFound)

        } else {

            let inverseSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: ".123456789").inverted

            return ((string as NSString).rangeOfCharacter(from: inverseSet).location == NSNotFound)
        }
```

this above will only allow the user to enter the "0" after the second character I mean restricts the user to type "0" at the starting of numbers